# How to display a map from a script in Grass Gis 7.6.1

Tags: raster, grass-gis, spyder

I am working with Grass Gis and spyder (IDE) and I am trying to display a map on "Spyder console" from the command line of spyder. I have a raster map call "elevation" and i tried this script:

```
import grass.script as gscript
def main():

    gscript.run_command('d.rast', map='elevation')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but the CONSOLE return this:

```
ERROR: Neither MONITOR (managed by d.mon command) nor
       GRASS_RENDER_IMMEDIATE (used for direct rendering) defined
```

I dont know what is GRASS_RENDER_INMEDIATE. If I can display in WxGui and not in "spyder console" maybe I can work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to Markus' answer, this works for me:

```
import grass.script as gscript

gscript.read_command('g.list', type="rast").strip().split("\n")
Out[3]: 
['ashalim_2014.1',
 'ashalim_2014.2',
 'ashalim_2014.3',
 'ashalim_2014_seg',
 'ashalim_composite']

gscript.run_command('d.mon', start='wx0')
Out[4]: 0

gscript.run_command('d.rast', map_='ashalim_composite')
Out[5]: 0
```

The raster does **not** appear in the spyder console (I don't think that's possible) rather in a new WX monitor window.

Comment: it's work, thank you so much!, is it posible to specify in what window of "wx0 or wx1 or wx2 ...." display the specific raster in the d.rast command? , and why you use "map_=" with underscore, thats mean something?

Comment: `d.mon select=wx1` to make a different window "active", then `d.rast...` to show in that window.  The argument name "map" is a python reserved work, so the '_' avoids errors in python.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first enable the rendering to file: see the [PNG driver](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/pngdriver.html) manual page.

To see existing code, you may take a look at the Python scripts in https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/blob/master/scripts (esp. those of the 'd.*' command family, e.g. [d.rast.leg.py](https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/blob/master/scripts/d.rast.leg/d.rast.leg.py#L110)).

Comment: Thanks markusN, I try the MICHA solution, but im gonna explore this too